# Unix Timestamp to HH-mm-ss

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.8

I'm converting UnixTimeSpan to Date, but I want to display just the Hours-Minutes-Seconds of it.
I'm trying with:

```
Public Shared Function UnixTimeStampToDateTime(ByVal unixTimeStamp As Double) As DateTime
        Dim dtDateTime As System.DateTime = New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc)
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime()
              Return dtDateTime
    End Function
```

which return a correct datetime

> 02/15/2022 20:23:24

but when I'm trying to display just The Hours-Minutes-seconds with:

```
 RichTextBox1.Text= UnixTimeStampToDateTime(CDbl(unxTS.tostring("HH:mm:ss")))
```

I'm getting the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "HH:mm:ss" to
> type 'Double' is not valid.'

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the format into the wrong place. Try

```vb
RichTextBox1.Text = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(CDbl(unxTS)).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

because `unxTS` is a numeric (I guess), not a datetime. The format string applies to datetime, which is returned by your function.